# How to convert a 4x4 matrix transformation to another coordinate system?

Tags: c#, math, coordinates, transformation

Is there a general method to convert a matrix transformation from one coordinate system to another, so that the resulting transformation looks the same on screen?

For example, there are some transformations in a coordinate system with X right, Y up, and Z toward the viewer. And they need to be converted to a coordinate system with X right, Y away from the viewer, and Z up.

[image]

What would be the operation that needs to be performed for each matrix so that the transformations look the same in the other coordinate system? And is there a general way to construct this operation given the source and destination basis vectors?

Comment: Matrix multiplication? Here we rotate pi `-pi / 2` around `X` axis so we should multiply initial vector `x; y; z` to rotation matrix `Rx` - `[1 0 0
 0 cos(fi) sin(fi)
 0 -sin(fi) cos(fi)]` https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

Comment: Thanks, but I am trying to convert matrices, not vectors. In the case of the image, it is easy as it is only a rotation. What I am really looking for is a general solution where you just enter the basis vectors and you get out a matrix that can be used for conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rotation around the x-axis by 90 degrees

```
┌                      ┐
│ 1   0       0      0 │
│ 0  cos(θ) -sin(θ)  0 │
│ 0  sin(θ)  cos(θ)  0 │
│ 0   0       0      1 │
└                      ┘
```

... where `cos(+/-90) = 0`, `sin(+/-90) = +/-1`

```
┌               ┐
│ 1   0   0   0 │
│ 0   0  -1   0 │
│ 0   1   0   0 │
│ 0   0   0   1 │
└               ┘
```

or by -90 degrees

```
┌               ┐
│ 1   0   0   0 │
│ 0   0   1   0 │
│ 0  -1   0   0 │
│ 0   0   0   1 │
└               ┘
```

I am not sure which one will help in your case. It's one of these things where, according to [Murphy's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy%27s_law), you are doing it the wrong way round the first time.

See: [3D Transformation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_graphics/3d_transformation.htm)

To convert the transformation formulated for the old coordinate system `T` into one for the new coordinate system `T'`, we can write by using the above rotation `R`

**T' = R<sup>-1</sup> × T × R**

The result is a transformation that converts a point in the new coordinate system back to the old one, then applies the original transformation and finally converts the result into the new coordinate system again.

Comment: Yes, this is correct, see more details and a complete solution including code here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/203073/how-to-convert-a-4x4-matrix-transformation-to-another-coordinate-system

Answer (score 1):

You just need to compose that matrix that does something you like with the appropriate coordinate transformation matrices. If you have a system A and some operation X on pts in that system you like, but you encode your points in system B for the same space and want to do what X does in space, then you can just apply X'=inv(M)*X*M where M is the coordinate transformation from B to A.

Comment: Yes, this is correct, see more details and a complete solution including code here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/203073/how-to-convert-a-4x4-matrix-transformation-to-another-coordinate-system